# Flutter: Need help displaying videos

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I am trying to create a tik tok ui clone in flutter. I want to display videos from my assets but the videos are not being displayed when I run the code. Can someone look over my code and give any recommendations?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const VideoTile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoTileState createState() => _VideoTileState();
}

class _VideoTileState extends State<VideoTile> {
  late VideoPlayerController _videoController;
  late Future _intitializeVideoPlayer;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _videoController = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/nft_vid1.mp4');
    _intitializeVideoPlayer = _videoController.initialize();
    _videoController.setLooping(true);
    _videoController.play();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _videoController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blue,
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: _intitializeVideoPlayer,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            return VideoPlayer(_videoController);
          } else {
            return Container(color: Colors.pink);
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AssetVideo extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  AssetVideoState createState() => AssetVideoState();
}

class AssetVideoState extends State<AssetVideo> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset('assets/nft_vid1.mp4');

    _controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
    _controller.setLooping(true);
    _controller.initialize().then((_) => setState(() {}));
    _controller.play();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

   @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Video Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: _controller.value.isInitialized
              ? AspectRatio(
                  aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                  child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
                )
              : Container(),
        ),
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              _controller.value.isPlaying
                  ? _controller.pause()
                  : _controller.play();
            });
          },
          child: Icon(
            _controller.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: The above code did not display any video. I do not want to create another material app. The video widget within my project will be used alongside a list of other similar widgets to create a discover page similar to the app tik tok and its UI.

Answer (score 0):

My original code was working. Just had to close out my IDE and restart my simulator.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem but I found out that the video is show when I remove the Container color parameter. Maybe this can help you.

Yet, I don't figure out how fix this. In others part of my code I have the Container color and the video is show...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).